# Swift cropping an image to remove bottom part

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimage, crop

Here is the image I wish to crop (to get rid of the options at the bottom. The Back, Draw and Delete are actual menu items, the ones above it are part of the image

[image]

this is the result of changing y: 100 and height : 1948

[image]

I want to remove the bottom 100 coordinates of an image. My application is on the iPad and all of the images are saved horizontally.
This code is one I took from stack overflow on a similar question, However it does not work for any values of x,y,width and height. The image is never cropped from the bottom.
Changing the values tends to only crop the image from the left and right (the 1536 pixel part of the iPad and not the 2048)

```
func cropImage(image: UIImage) -> UIImage {

    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1536, height: 2048) //    1536 x 2048 pixels

    let cgImage = image.cgImage!

    let croppedCGImage = cgImage.cropping(to: rect)
    return UIImage(cgImage: croppedCGImage!)
}
```

Does anyone know what is missing? All i need it to crop out the bottom part as the images are saves of a previous view (however the menu options appear in a a=stack view in the bottom which are still there when I save the image, hence the crop. Thanks

Comment: Note: I have tried changing each element in CGRect, however each one will keep the bottom pixels

Comment: Can you show your original image and the results of your cropping attempt? The documentation here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgimage/1454683-cropping suggests your code is correct.

Comment: Also, can you show the result of `print(image.size)` and `print(image.scale)` thanks.

Comment: A compromise I am using (although is not great at all), is: setting the CGRect to be:
let height = CGFloat(image.size.height - 800).          
let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: height - 150, width: image.size.width - 150, height: height)

Comment: @mcgeevej - the *"image I wish to crop"* image you posted is `2048 x 1536` pixels... if you want to crop the *"bottom 100 pixels"* your crop rect should be `CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 2048, height: 1536 - 100)`. It seems odd, though, that your code appears to be drawing on an image (view), but the image you want to crop is a screen-capture?

Comment: Yes, i saved users drawing as an image, and am now displaying it (after saving it to core data). But thank you DonMag - your solution worked. I did not realise the height value counts from the top of the image!

Comment: Sorry, I am new to posting here - how do I accept an answer if it is in a comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "image I wish to crop" image you posted is 2048 x 1536 pixels...

If you want to crop the "bottom 100 pixels" your crop rect should be

```
CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 2048, height: 1536 - 100)
```